# OAuth / OpenId MVC 4 App with a WebAPI

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0

I've been looking at the DotNetOpenAuth samples and reading around the subject but I'm still a bit hazy on what the actual requirements are for me to secure my particular environment.  Many of the samples I've looked at also throw exceptions making walking the code a bit hit and miss.

I have an MVC web app making use of the WebSecurity and OAuthWebSecurity classes, this provides the app with logins using either a local account or an OpenID provider account.  The system also has a WebAPI in a separate web site and solution.

The system has two databases, one for security and one for data.  The MVC web application only has a direct link to the security database whereas the Api has a connection to the security database and the data database.  All interaction with the data database will occur via the WebApi.

What I looking to do is secure the Api.

I'm not sure of the terminology in relation to OAuth to describe the Api.  Is it a Resource Server Authorisation / Authentication Sever rolled into one?  It also seems like at times it will also be the relying party.

The Api is also going to be used by 3rd party apps on behalf of users so I also need an API key for the applications authentication.  The users and apps will be logged in purely by the Api.

Any clarification on what needs to be done would be really appreciated.

Comment: Can not just deploy them over HTTPS?

Comment: Unless my understanding SSL is wildly off the only way of authenticating with SSL is with specific client / server certificates.  Not really suitable in this situation as that would bring it's own certificate management issues to deal with.